# Creating a `Users` show page using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, show

I'm trying to create a User `show` page (that will function as a profile page) but am confused about how to do this with Devise.  It doesn't seem as though Devise comes with any sort of `show` definition - is there any way I can access the controllers Devise is implementing in order to make one or do I have to override them?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You should generate a `users_controller` which inherits from `application_controller` and define there your custom `show` method. Don't forget to create a view and routes for it.
Ex:

```
#users_controller.rb
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

#in your view
<%= @user.name %>

#routes.rb
match 'users/:id' => 'users#show', via: :get
# or 
get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
# or
resources :users, only: [:show]
```

Comment: So I have done all of that, I just changed `show` to `index` which made it `@users = Users.all` but I get this error: uninitialized constant UsersController::Users.

Found my error, should be `@users = @User.all`

Comment: Once I do this, how can I link to a specific users profile and have it be open/accessible without being logged in? Thanks!

Comment: The code above will make user show (profile) page accessible without being logged in

Comment: When I do this, I lose the ability to reach the `sign_in` page

Comment: @JeremyThomas do you have `devise_for :users` in your routes?

Comment: @SergeyKishenin it ended up being an issue due to the order of my routes

Comment: It worked great for me and thank you for this valuable information. I just might add if this is troublesome on rails 5 you might try to do it with each method on the view part.
thanks again

Comment: I used the command "rails g controller Users show" - this creates the show view and the route automatically for you - you will need to edit the route though

Answer (score 40):

Don't forget that your users routes should be below the devise_for users routes, like this:

```
#routes.rb
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => [:show]
```

Also, if you are using a username or an email as the primary key instead of the usual id, you should avoid routing conflicts by declaring your routes as follow:

```
#routes.rb
devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'd'
resources :users, :only => [:show]
```

Answer (score 24):

showing current_user/ other_user profiles with devise:

> After installing devise

Create a Users controller:

```
rails generate controller Users
```

Then create a show action and find the user with params id:

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Create a show.html.erb file in the User view folder:

```
<%= @user.email %>
```

Linking to users show page:

```
<%= link_to "current_user_show", current_user %>
```

Now if you want to view other profiles create a index action in the users controller:

```
def index @users = User.all end
```

Create an index.html.erb in the User view folder then:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= link_to user.username, user %>
<%= user.email %>
<% end %>
```

The link for this will be:

```
<%= link_to "show_index_of_users", users_path %>
```

This will link you to the users index.html.erb file there you will create a loop and link to users profile:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= link_to user.username, user %>
<%= user.email %>
<% end %>
```

This should work!

Comment: No need to config/routes?

Comment: Yes- def need to config routes as noted in accepted answer.

resources :users, only: [:show]

Answer (score 0):

The `users_controller.rb` should be outside of the `devise` generated `users` folder containing the `sessions` and `registration` controllers *(if any)*.

```
# controllers/users_controller.rb
class  UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

For your views:

```
# views/users/show.html.erb
<h1><%= @user.some_user_attribute_here %></h1>
```

and for your routes:

```
# config/routes.rb
  get '/users/:id', to: 'users#show'
```

The `show` route should also be separate from the custom `devise` generated ones *(if any)*.

Answer (score -12):

you can generate the views used by devise, so you can change it as you want to.

```
 rails g devise:views
```

Comment: but there is still no show page for users. only new and edit pages.

Comment: bad answer, read the question first, it seems oyu have not work with devise before

Comment: `rails g devise:views` generates the views for new and edit. No show page. Try the code and view your routes, there is no show.