# Creating a "Users" show page with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to create a User show page which will act as a dashboard. I believe that I've made good progress following the advice listed here: [Creating a `Users` show page using Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086583/creating-a-users-show-page-using-devise) but I'm not quite there yet.

I've done the following so far:

**Created the show method in the users_controller.rb file**

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

**Created the route in routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users
resources :users, :only => [:show]
```

**Created the view show.html.erb under devise/registrations/show.html.erb**

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

Now I would assume that I could access this page for user with ID=1 via localhost:3000/users/1, however when I do so I receive the error:

> Missing template users/show, application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], >:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "c:/Users
>   /Evan/Desktop/reviewdraft/app/views" * "c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
>   /gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"

Any advice on how I could resolve this error?

Comment: Try moving `show.html.erb` to `app/views/users/show.html.erb` I'm guessing the problem is that the current location isn't in the expected location for that controller action. Alternatively, you can probably use `render` in the action to spit out the file's current location, but putting it in the right place is probably a lot cleaner overall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quiet apparent from error if you notice it: `Missing template users/show`. It's asking you to create a show.html.erb in users directory.

You need to create view here: **app/views/users/show.html.erb** not at **devise/registrations/show.html.erb**, because you're inheriting `UsersController` from `ApplicationController`, which is no way related to Devise. Create *app/views/users/show.html.erb* with this and try again:

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still new to Rails but after re-reading this answer and the error message it was very apparent what it was suggesting. Work fine now!

Answer (score 1):

showing current_user/ other_user profiles with devise:

> After installing devise

Create a Users controller:

```
rails generate controller Users
```

Then create a show action and find the user with params id:

```
def show
@user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Create a show.html.erb file in the User view folder:

```
<%= @user.email %>
```

Linking to users show page:

```
<%= link_to "current_user_show", current_user %>
```

Now if you want to view other profiles create a index action in the users controller:

```
def index 
@users = User.all 
end
```

Create an index.html.erb in the User view folder then:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= link_to user.username, user %>
<%= user.email %>
<% end %>
```

The link for this will be:

```
<%= link_to "show_index_of_users", users_path %>
```

This will link you to the users index.html.erb file there you will create a loop and link to users profile:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= link_to user.username, user %>
<%= user.email %>
<% end %>
```

This should work!

Comment: what about the routes.rb file? what would this look like?

Comment: installing devise will automatically generate - devise_for :users - in the routes.rb / You may also want to add - resources :users - if you want to check what routes are generated by add them two - go to your terminal and type in - rake routes

Answer (score -1):

Devise comes with its own views. There is no need to write user views by your own self. To generate the views use this generator: `rails generate devise:views`
All needed views will be generated under ***app/views/devise***
There you can access the logged in user by `current_user` variable.